# How can i load image with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow

line 320, in predictImage
img = image.load_img(img_path)
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'

`
def predictImage(img_path='Normal2.jpg', arrayImg=None, printData=True):
crops = []

```
if arrayImg is None:
    
    img = image.load_img(img_path)
    
    crops = np.array(getCropImgs(img, needRotations=False), dtype=np.float16)
    crops /= 255.0

Image.fromarray(np.array(crops[2], dtype=np.uint8), "RGB").show()

classes = ["Freundlich", "Anstehend", "Übergriffig", "Normal"]
compProbs = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for i in range(len(crops)):
    if printData:
        print("\n\nCrop " + str(i + 1) + " Vohersage:\n")

    _, probs = predict(crops[i], modelSavePath, showImg=False)

    for j in range(len(classes)):
        if printData:
            print(f"{classes[j]} : {round(probs[j], 4)}%")
        compProbs[j] += probs[j]

if printData:
    print("\n\nDurchschnitt aus allen\n")

for j in range(len(classes)):
    if printData:
        print(f"{classes[j]} : {round(compProbs[j] / len(crops), 4)}%")`
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve your Problem erorr, you should import the funktion 'tensorflow.keras.prorocessing' instead of 'keras.preprocing'